# Force IEnumerable<T> to evaluate without calling .ToArray() or .ToList()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable, lazy-evaluation

If I query EF using something like this...

```
IEnumerable<FooBar> fooBars = db.FooBars.Where(o => o.SomeValue == something);
```

IIRC, This creates a lazy-evaluated, iterable state machine in the background, that does not yet contain any results; rather, it contains an expression of "how" to obtain the results when required.

If I want to force the collection to contain results I have to call `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`

Is there a way to force an `IEnumerable<T>` collection to contain results without calling `.ToArray()` or `.ToList();` ?

**Rationale**

I don't know if the CLR is capable of doing this, but essentially I want to forcibly create an evaluated collection that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, but is implemented under the hood by the CLR, thus **NOT** a `List<T>` or `Array<T>`

Presumably this is not possible, since I'm not aware of any CLR capability to create in-memory, evaluated collections that implement `IEnumerable<T>`

**Proposal**

Say for example, I could write something like this:

```
var x = IEnumerable<FooBar> fooBars = db.FooBars
        .Where(o => o.SomeValue == something)
        .Evaluate(); // Does NOT return a "concrete" impl such as List<T> or Array<T>

Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name);
// eg. <EvaluatedEnumerable>e__123
```

Comment: What is wrong with calling `.ToList()` ?

Comment: Yes. By using the `Foreach` loop.

Comment: The results have to be stored in *something*, so you need a list, array or some other collection type.

Comment: put off lazy initialization, data is directly retrieved...

Comment: Enumerables are just the way to iterate a collection, you can't force them to do something they aren't responsible for. Enumerables don't create state machines themselves, it is the `yield` keyword which does

Comment: The sequence doesn't have to store the values somewhere; it can return values as it is enumerated. Otherwise you'd need infinite storage for something like `IEnumerable<int> InfiniteOnes() { while (true) yield return 1; }`

Comment: `IEnumerable<FooBar> fooBars = db.FooBars.Where(o => o.SomeValue == something).ToList();` does exactly what you stated in your update.

Comment: @user3185569 but surely .ToList() returns List<T>, does it not?

Comment: @series0ne Yes. `IEnumerable` is an interface. It is a contract or a behavior. It is not a concrete type to hold your data.

Comment: It seems my comment asking for explanation of why is this necessary was moderated. Really? Perfectly valid question? Not materializing results to achieve what? Can you explain why do you want to run query without storing result? I suspect you are going to use result later. How exactly?

Comment: @Sinatr basically say I query the db in order to collect one set of information, which I then want to use in a subsequent query. IEnumerable<T> causes a problem because it's trying to enumerate the results of the first query, in order to execute the second query, which causes an exception in EF. So, all I wanted to know is if it's possible to evalutate the collection under the hood (get the CLR to do it), without concreting to List<T> or Array<T>

Comment: @series0ne, subsequent query? Use [`AsQueryable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003(v=vs.100).aspx). This way you do not materialize results yet, but e.g. constructing complicated query which will be executed some time later.

Comment: @Sinatr I tried that and it just threw the same exception :-(

Comment: So this is indeed an X-Y question. I think you should ask for a solution to the exception rather than asking how to actualise a sequence without storing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to force an `IEnumerable<T>` collection to contain results without calling `.ToArray()` or `.ToList();` ?

Yes, but it is perhaps not what you want:

```
IEnumerable<T> source = …;
IEnumerable<T> cached = new List<T>(source);
```

The thing is, `IEnumerable<T>` is not a concrete type. It is an interface (contract) representing an item sequence. There can be any concrete type "hiding behind" this interface; some might only represent a query, others actually hold the queried items in memory.

If you want to force-evaluate your sequence so that the result is actually stored in physical memory, you need to make sure that the concrete type behind `IEnumerable<T>` is a in-memory collection that holds the results of the evaluation. The above code example does just that.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this is the actual implementation of the `.ToList()` method beyond the hoods.

Comment: To second @user3185569, you can see this in the [.NET source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs).

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in fooBars) { }
```

Note that this evaluates all items in `fooBars`, but throws away the result immediately. Next time you run the same `foreach` loop or `.ToArray()`, `.ToList()`, the enumerable will be evaluated once again.

Comment: Then *collection contains results* as the OP stated ? No, it is enumerated each time you do a foreach loop. `IEnumerable` contains info on how to get data and not the data itself. Unless the run-time type is a List and the compile time type is `IEnumerable`. (eg `IEnumerable<FooBar> fooBars = db.FooBars.Where(o => o.SomeValue == something).ToList();`

Comment: Why would you ever suggest to do so? What is the point? To run query for nothing?

Comment: @Sinatr: In theory, the query could have side effects, so the seemingly empty loop might actually do something. A query having side effects is not exactly a good thing IMO, but it's a possibility nevertheless.

Comment: @Sinatr: Also re: _"Why would you ever suggest to do so?"_, basically because the OP asked for it.

Comment: @stakx No the OP did not. The OP did not ask *How to enumerate an IEnumerable without a .ToList() call?*. But asked how to *force an IEnumerable<T> collection to contain results*. His question doesn't have an answer except **It can't be done**

Comment: @user3185569: If we're being very pedantic, then yes, it can be done: There are many ways to create an in-memory collection apart from `.ToList()` and `.ToArray()`. For example, you can call `.ToLookup()`, using a constant key selector. Or you can use `new List<T>(…)`. Or you can implement your own collection type and convert to that. If we're being less pedantic, then you are right: Evaluating an `IEnumerable<T>` so that it "contains its results" requires some sort of (usually in-memory) persistence, which is what collections are for, so if they're not allowed, then this becomes impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Another options is:

```
<linq expression>.All( x => true);
```

Comment: .All just returns an expression but does not immediately evaluate the expression.

Comment: not according to https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: Looking at the source between options, this looks like it is the most efficient way to do it, as branch prediction should make this basically a non-op with no allocation.

Answer (score 2):

A concrete use case I've run into revolves around needing to ensure that an IEnumerable that wraps a DB Query has begun returning results (indicating that the query did not time out) before returning control to the calling method. But the results are too large to evaluate fully, hence the IEnumerable to support streaming.

```
internal class EagerEvaluator<T>
{
    private readonly T _first;
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    private readonly bool _hasFirst;

    public EagerEvaluator(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        if (_enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            _hasFirst = true;
            _first = _enumerator.Current;                
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable()
    {
        if (_hasFirst)
        {
            yield return _first;

            while (_enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return _enumerator.Current;                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is pretty straight forward:

```
IEnumerable<FooBar> fooBars = new EagerEvaluator(fooBars).ToEnumerable()
```

Comment: This evaluates the first item but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Aggregate<T>()` to evaluate an `IEnumerable<T>` with side effects:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Evaluate<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    => source.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), (evaluated, s) => evaluated.Append(s));
```

See it in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iya2l0